Internal Induction and the Overflow Principle
On page 129 of Goldblatt's Lectures on the Hyperreals, I'm trying to understand the discussion between Internal Induction (Thm 11.3.2) and the Overflow Principle (Thm 11.4.1).
For context:
Theorem 11.3.2 (Internal Induction): If $X$ is an internal subset of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ that contains $1$ and is closed under the successor function $n\mapsto n+1$, then $X={}^*\mathbb{N}$.
[Proof is in the book, and I understand it.]
The set $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be internal, or else by internal induction it would be equal to ${}^*\mathbb{N}$. [I understand this.]
Thus, if an internal set $X$ contains all members of $\mathbb{N}$, then since $X$ cannot be equal to $\mathbb{N}$, it must "overflow" into ${}^*\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, we will see that $X$ must contain the initial segment of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ up to some unlimited hypernatural. In fact, a slightly stronger statement than this can be demonstrated by assuming only that $X$ contains "almost all" members of $\mathbb{N}$:
Theorem 11.4.1 (Overflow Principle): Let $X$ be an internal subset of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. If $n\in X$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\le n$, then there is an unlimited $K\in{}^*\mathbb{N}$ with $n\in X$ for all $n\in{}^*\mathbb{N}$ with $k\le n\le K$.
[Proof is in the book, and I understand it.]
Okay, so I have a somewhat philosophical issue with what's going on. In the paragraph before Theorem 11.4.1, he claims that an internal set which contains $\mathbb{N}$ must "overflow" into ${}^*\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{N}$. I understand this, but why talk about overflow into ${}^*\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{N}$, when in fact by internal induction one could say $X$ "fills up" and is equal to ${}^*\mathbb{N}$? Why is he seeming to conclude that in this case, $X$ would only contain all hypernaturals up to some fixed unlimited hypernatural?
What's worse for me is that the case $k=1$ in Theorem 11.4.1 seems to further strengthen his position that $X$ only contains hypernaturals up to a certain unlimited one. But again for $k=1$, we can conclude $X={}^*\mathbb{N}$ by internal induction. So we can make a much stronger conclusion in the case $k=1$.
So what am I missing or not thinking about in the right way? What can overflow do that internal induction can't? Does the strength of overflow lie only in the case $k>1$? (For $k=1$, internal induction leads to a stronger conclusion.)

Ohhh, I see. Assuming $k=1$, I was thinking it was closed under successors since it contains all of $\mathbb{N}$, but it's not necessarily closed under successors of unlimited hypernaturals. Thank you

Is your question resolved? If not, try to edit to tell us what parts of it are still remaining

Yes, my question was answered by a comment that was deleted.

Here it may be helpful to keep in mind the axiomatic viewpoint.  Here all numbers are natural (not hypernatural) but come in two types: standard and nonstandard.  From this point of view, one is unlikely to think that induction should somehow apply only to some numbers but not all.

My question was answered by a comment that got deleted. The $X$ in Theorem 11.4.1 is not closed under all hypernatural successors (it is closed under natural number successors but is not necessarily closed under unlimited hypernatural successors). So we cannot apply Theorem 11.3.2 to the $X$ in Theorem 11.4.1 when $k=1$ to conclude any more than just overflow.
